# Write access (post answers, comments etc. on behalf of users)

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

From what I can tell, there's currently no way to **write** to StackExchange sites using the API. Are there any plans to support this? This would mean some implementation headaches, such as providing a way to log a user in through the API and then call API methods on behalf of that user (to post/edit questions/answers/comments).

The simplest system for authenticating users through the API would, in my opinion, be something à la [bit.ly](http://bit.ly). If you're not familiar with it, they basically provide each user with their own private, unique, secret API key which they can give to an app and the app will then be able to perform actions on behalf of that user, using that API key. The user can reset his key at any time, if an app goes berserk.

Comment: I totally agree that write access needs to be put into the API, but I would prefer seeing OAuth as the authentication method.

Comment: Writing Questions, Answers, and Comments is now supported by API version 2.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[It's explained here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/)

> **Version 1 is read only**. Coming up with
>   a solid API is hard enough without
>   adding writing and authentication to
>   the mix. For the initial release, it’s
>   a read-only API. We’ll take on the
>   much more challenging problem of
>   writing (and authentication) in v2.

Comment: This is the correct answer.