# Post questions using API

Tags: support

Can I use the API for posting any question to Stack Overflow? I have a internal SharePoint site and whenever anybody has got any technical question they post it here. I want to post it automatically to Stack Overflow so that it can be addressed by a larger audience.

Comment: It seems like this question gets asked every week, but I can't find the original or any duplicates (they're probably being deleted).  Perhaps it should be added to the [FAQ](http://stackapps.com/faq) or even the Getting Started sidebar?

Comment: [Write Access?](http://stackapps.com/questions/276/write-access-post-answers-comments-etc-on-behalf-of-users), [Timeline for 2.0](http://stackapps.com/questions/1074/timeline-for-v2-0-of-the-api), [Post Methods?](http://stackapps.com/questions/1049/why-does-the-api-lack-any-post-methods), [Post API?](http://stackapps.com/questions/1256/is-there-an-api-to-post-questions-without-using-the-websites-interface)

Comment: Yikes, this use case is scary... makes a very good argument for WHY write access *should* take a long time to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't post anything (Question, Answers, Comments, Votes) from the API yet.  [It's been implied](https://stackapps.com/questions/1074/timeline-for-v2-0-of-the-api/1076#1076) (but not promised) that write access will be available in version 2.0.

Comment: Haha - "It's been implied (but not promised)" - They have done a very good job of not promising anything.  " *When* v2 comes out..." They keep telling us.

Answer (score 2):

Many have asked, some have even tried playing around with issuing POST requests. It just isn't going to happen until v2.0 or later.